# Visual Studio 2012 debugger not working (c programming)

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I'm not very well versed with programming myself. I'm currently a student and we're learning c. 
My issue with Visual Studio 2012 now is though that out of the blue the debugger is not working anymore.
Whenever I try to debug it just loads endlessly and the only thing I can do is to use the task manager to close visual studio.
Thing is this happened with 2015 as well and I cannot open any of my old projects' .exe files.
I have tried the following:

**1.** Restart computer numerous times.

**2.** Repair Visual Studio

**3.** Try out 2015(which did the exact same thing)

**4.** Uninstall everything Visual Studio related and reinstall 2012

**5.** Google for possible solutions, landed here and tried to search but nothing helped as of yet.

Hope someone can help me with my problem.
I'm running win7 64bit. Most of the programms I tried didn't even have any scetchy code. Mostly a main function and just a return.

/edit
Avast was the cause of this in case anyone finds this topic.

Comment: First step - Verify your Net Framework installation with this [.NET Framework setup verification tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2013/11/06/10464416.aspx)

Comment: "loads endlessly" - what does it load? Symbols? "I cannot open any of my old projects' .exe files" - typically you open projects or solutions, but not exe files.

Comment: Do you use Avast antivirus? There have been several recent questions where Avast is causing this or similar problems.

Comment: It was avast. Thank you Blastfurnace!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running my c++ code in visual studio gives me a blank cmd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-in-visual-studio-gives-me-a-blank-cmd)