# Visual Studio C++ console application doesn't run any code

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I've been having great issues with Visual Studio 2015 for my computer science class. I use C++ and we have been working with console windows the whole semester. Recently every time that I have tried to run any program, the console window will appear but no code will run. I assume it must be an issue with Visual Studio since even the most basic code will not run;

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to debug this (using ctrl + F5), this is all I get with every program:
[Console Window with no code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jWpN.jpg)

I uninstalled Visual Studio and then reinstalled it, but the same error keeps occurring. I'm quite new to Visual Studio so I tried to include as much information as I could, but I really don't understand what is happening. I'm not sure if there's something simple that I'm doing wrong or if there's a more complex issue. Does anyone know what I can do to run programs normally again?

Comment: Are you running Avast anti-virus program?  What you describe matches the symptoms of a well known problem between Avast and VS.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-cmd

Comment: Yes I am running Avast. Now that you mention it I remember that I've only started running Avast recently, so that may be the issue. What can I do to deal with it?

Comment: See the link I added.  This question comes up frequently.