# Blank Console Window when Running Program from Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

When I try to build and run a new program in Code::Blocks, the console window pops up blank and I have to click the exit button to stop it. It does this for any new project I have tried including "Hello world". Oddly it works normally for any older projects that I have.

I looked in toolchain executables for both my new projects and the old and everything is identical. It's not a problem with my code because if I copy and paste it into an old project file, it runs as it should.

I'm running Code::Blocks 13.12 on Windows 10.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you running Avast?

Comment: Yes, I am running Avast.

Comment: Turn it off and try again.  There have been problems with it.  see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-cmd

Comment: Excluding the directory from avast did the trick, Thank you!

Comment: This post should have never been closed based on the link provided, where problem is listed as a ***Visual Studios*** related problem: _I'm trying to run some c++ code in Visual Studio 2015._  This post specifically asks a question about a very annoying ***Code::Blocks*** issue.  And although _Avast_ in this case was the culprit, there are more commonly occurring reasons why people continue to ask the question:  _Why is console appearing when running simple executable in Code::Blocks?_  Even the linked _duplicate_ has a comment asking that answer be generalized for Code::Blocks. it is not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit vague. Here is my idea , go to settings compiler and them press 'reset defaults' then click 'ok' you should have a pop-up with your compiler ussually something like 'GNU/GCC' if not download here http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe
This works with and second when you are making the project make sure you have a valid location on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

Could you test if it works when not in debug? By compiling a release (as an example)?
If it works without debug, I suppose it could have something to do with the debugger or the linker.

Check the linker syntax, to be sure it is `-Wl,--enable-auto-import`
You can find those options here;

```
"Settings" -> "Compiler and debugger..."
"Global compiler settings"
"Linker settings"
```

Like **NathanOlivier** said, you should try to add an exclusion for your "\Visual Studio 2015\Projects" directory for Avast.
[Running my C++ code gives me a blank console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-cmd) (See the solution by **Blastfurnace**)

Comment: The OP is using code blocks not VS so the folders will be different.

Comment: Excluding it worked. Thanks, guys!