# Suppress popup console in apps created using Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: codeblocks

I am using *[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/)* version 13.12 with the GNU GCC Compiler.  I recently installed and started using these tools on Windows 7.  Although I do not believe language is a contributing factor, I use this environment to create both C and C++ applications.

After getting a clean build for either a debug or release target executable, and click on either the green "Run" or the red "Debug/Run" toolbar button, I see a console popup flicker (appear, then close) even for code that writes nothing to `stdout`.  For example...

```
int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

...produces a console popup.

Can anyone describe how to set the Code::Blocks IDE to suppress the console popup?

*Note:* I have reviewed answers related to this question *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34341839/blank-console-window-when-running-program-from-codeblocks)* and *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36237213/how-to-remove-execution-related-text-from-output-window-of-codeblocks)*.  These posts are related in that one is closed as a duplicate of the other, but answers for neither address this question.  (i.e. Because my systems do not use *[Avast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avast_Software)*, Avast is completely unrelated to the issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the settings in Code::Blocks to run as a GUI application. This will tell it to compile as such and it will not produce a console window on startup. And this is how you do so:

```
1. Click Project on the CodeBlocks menu.  
2. Click Properties.  
3. Click the second tab, Build Targets.  
4. On the right, where it says Type: Console application, change it to GUI application.  
5. Rebuild the project.
```

This is where the information was gather if you have further questions: [How to get ride of console box of a GUI program compile by MinGW + Code::Block](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10003777/7340690)