# How can I prevent the console from showing up in a Code::Blocks project?

Tags: c, sdl, codeblocks

I tried various guides, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42307989/suppress-or-show-popup-console-when-using-codeblocks-ide) where they tell you to turn the project into a "GUI project", but to no avail. So what can I do?

Comment: That should've worked. Did you rebuild the project after making the change?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Create yourself an answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I needed to do was to REbuild the project, which is an entirely different thing from just building it again.