# C++ command prompt

Tags: c++, cmd, ide

my program does not display in command prompt when i run it (even when the codes are correct, I tested with the simplest program of all- Hello World). I usually work with Code Blocks, I thought that was the problem but encountered the same problem with DEV C++. I have followed a couple of instruction online to get the problem resolved using Dev C++, the problem persist. Please help
See attached picture.

[image: cpp_cmd]

Comment: Please post a [Minimal complete verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Does it work if you run the program directly from the console, without any IDE?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong -- really, Microsoft Windows is simply not the best platform for learning C++ development (let the flame wars begin!)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How dare you! Windows is the best platform for learning anything! Arrgh...

Comment: @Dotun You either forgot to recompile or there is that kind of mistake. It's not really related to C++ and, especially, [compiler-construction]

Comment: There's too little info to go on to say how exactly you're using the IDE incorrectly. But here's a way to get progress: *use the compiler from the Windows command line, cmd.exe*. That way you ensure that you're actually compiling your source, and that you're actually running your program, and you get error messages if you don't get this right.

Comment: @Ben: it's a standard hello world with no pause.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yeah i saw the picture, but its not exactly verifiable: http://ideone.com/Lt8NIb, point is, too little info.

Comment: @Ben Heh. You haven't reproduced it properly. You need Windows 10, Dev C++ 5.4 and a project created on the path shown in the title bar. ;)

Comment: @Drop: Oh! Maybe it's the spaces in the paths. As I recall Code::Blocks has a problem with path spaces, and maybe then also DevC++?

Comment: Yet another avast problem? Or did I guess the issue wrong?

Comment: @Dotun Also notice that executable path and filename (in console window's title bar) are very different from the project path and name. You might confuse executable etc.

Comment: @drescherjm Haha. Avast and AVG is more like anti-VisualStudio things. Do they also mess with MinGW?

Comment: They mess with unknown executables. Any program you compile will be in that category.. I have seen at least a dozen threads were avast was the cause of the can't run my c++ program in the last 3 or so days.

Comment: Thanks Guys, AVAST was the problem. i turned off firewall and real-time shield, BOOM!!!  my program appeared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running my c++ code gives me a blank console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console)

Answer (score 1):

There may be several reasons why the console application run from IDE does not show message.
I am trying to consider some of them.

1. Your program ends immediately after start and printed text disappears for some reason
   (in some IDE console window for your code will appear for a fraction of a second)
   Add some code that will wait input, e.g.:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{      
    int number;
    cout << "Enter a number, please" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    return 0;
}
```

2. Your IDE executes previously compiled program that was build from source code without any output.
   Try to clean current project and then rebuild it again (or create new project with the same code)
3. Perhaps, properties of your console window do not allow you to see printed text.
   Make sure that Screen text color is set to light (Move mouse arrow to top-left corner of console screen -> right-click -> properties -> colors tab -> Screen text option -> select a color)

[image]