# Visual Studio. Empty command prompt window when trying to run a program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Please be forgiving, I'm new to programing. Recently Visual Studio stopped working properly. I tried my classic way of fixing things, which is reinstalling, but apparently VS remembers all settings. Trying to run any program results in something [like this](http://pasteboard.co/uQsddj4.jpg), an empty command prompt. Has anyone encountered a similar problem, or knows how to completely remove all VS settings? I believe the problem is with my PC because when I work from e.g. school library everything is working fine.

Comment: Are you running avast? If so disable it and try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console

Comment: Does this happen with x64 Debug mode too?

Answer (score 0):

You may easily reset all Visual Studio settings in `Tools -> Import and Export settings`.

Another option is to create an experimental instance (new "profile") of Visual Studio with [CreateExpInstance utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875761.aspx).

Comment: I already have, but the problem remains. Thanks for the help though

Comment: @RobertOstrowski, another option is to create experimental instance of Visual Studio with [CreateExpInstance utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd875761.aspx). Such instance is a completely independent set of VS settings. If it will not help, then the problem probably is not in settings.