# Visual Studio crashes when vector is included

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, crash, include

So here is an interesting problem, I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 and I had a big function that was using dynamically allocated arrays and decided to use vectors instead, it then crashed (you couldn't kill it with task manager) so I removed the function and it still crashed (even with no reference to it), so by now my code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string menu = "path; {tag1,tag2,tag3}";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

and it still crashes! so I remove the `#include <vector>` and then it works.

I'm new to vectors so I'm not sure if this is an obvious question, or I'm just missing something, but I couldn't find anything on the internet about it.

Thanks!

**EDIT** I've also tried it with Visual Studio 2015 and it still crashes.

Comment: If that code really does crash then it's a bug in VC++ and you should report it to Microsoft.

Comment: I tried it on VS.NET 2013 premuime and nothign goes wrong.. could you try your code in a new blank project?

Comment: I tried it, it still crashes!

Comment: How does it crash? Do you have a stack trace or even a crash message?

Comment: Does Visual Studio crash, or does your program crash?  If the former, I suspect a corrupt file somewhere.

Comment: Yes, visual studio freezes and the program doesn't open but it is visible in task manager

Comment: Is this the reason? [Running my C++ code gives me a blank console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console)

Comment: No, I don't think that's the problem, the console window doesn't even come up

Comment: So you're using the Debug feature in Visual Studio to start the program you compiled?

Comment: Did you alter the vector file in any way?  Did you try to run your project without breakpoints? Did you try it with only one breakpoint at the first line in main? Are you using a final version or a RC?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your program. Do one thing report same thing to microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Oops! looks like it was my AV, I disabled Avast and it worked!

Thanks anyway!