# Why aren't my C programs dying or working?

Tags: c, git-bash, msys

I'm learning C and everything is going wrong. The very simple programs I'm compiling are spawning three of the same processes all of which I can't kill — not through taskmanager, taskkill, or ctrl+c. For instance this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

will only work if I write it in `vim` and run it with `cmd` prompt NOT git `bash`. Yet if I write the same program in atom text editor and run it with `cmd` prompt it doesn't work. The `cmd` prompt becomes unresponsive to further commands as well as git `bash` and it spawns three unkillable processes.

What's going wrong?  How do I get sane behaviour?

Comment: Is it possible that atom is using a wrong character encoding?

Comment: Could this be it?? How do I check?

Comment: I just tried writing it in notepad++ and it didn't work.

Comment: I just tried it on CodingGround and it works fine.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php
I copied your code, pasted it there, compiled the program, and then executed it. 
What are you doing to compile and run the program?

Comment: jdigital - I'm compiling using g++. The only difference is the directory and text editor. If I compile it on desktop it works but if I go into a folder on desktop and compile/execute it the command prompt no longer accepts input

Comment: bash doesn't include the current directory in the path,  when running your program from bash, you should include the path of the executable.  you might be running a different program rather than the one you just compiled.

Comment: jdigital that's cpp I'm using .c. Also it's not the code it's the directory I'm compiling in I think.

Comment: This is puzzling!  Can you provide a screenshot of your hung terminal window?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ZgMcvFg.png

Comment: compiling the program that works on desktop with a different name causes it to hang too btw.

Comment: This is a complete stab in the dark, but does it do anything different if you rename the "dev" folder? (I'm wondering if msys is doing something silly to emulate `/dev` or something like that)

Comment: Can you show the compilation command and messages?

Comment: Another try: can you add `fflush(stdout);` after `printf("Enter a number: ");` ?

Comment: @user5800226: This may sound odd but do you use Avast antivirus? The unkillable tasks sound like a common Avast problem with false-positives.

Comment: @Blastfurnace yes I use Avast and will attempt to turn it off and try tomorrow (on mobile)

Comment: @Blastfurnace just did some googling and found an article that says avast caused 3 unkillable processes. Exactly like my situation https://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=180904.0

Comment: @user5800226: Yeah, I've been flagging duplicate reports of the Avast problem in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console). It's being reported by gcc and Visual C++ users.