# cout/cin not reading or printing

Tags: c++, c++11, cout, cin

I'm probably not using `cin` correctly here, but can someone tell me why this small program will not run and produce any output?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vector {
public:
   Vector(int s) :elem{new double[s]}, sz{s} {}
  ~Vector() { delete[] elem; } //added this
   double& operator[](int i) { return elem[i]; }
   int size() { return sz; }
private:
   double *elem;
   int sz;
};

double read_and_sum(int s) {
   Vector v(s);
   for (int i=0; i != v.size(); ++i)
      //cin>>v[i];
      v[i]=s;
      cout<<"s = "<<s<<"\n";

   double sum = 0;
      for (int i=0; i != v.size(); ++i)
         sum+=v[i];
   return sum;
}

int main()
{
   int i = 0;
   cout<<"Please enter an integer: ";
   cin >> i;
   cout<<"Sum = "<<read_and_sum(i)<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. [Works for me](http://rextester.com/APFMV10845). Are you actually entering 20 double values on standard input? Most likely, the program is waiting for you to type something.

Comment: How are you compiling it? How are you running it?

Comment: g++ -o vector_3 vector_3.cc -std=c++11

Comment: ./vector_3 to run it

Comment: You have a memory leak.

Comment: Do you know where exactly?

Comment: You have a new with out a delete []

Comment: @Andrew: Hint: Whenever you allocate with `new`, you should also be deallocating later with `delete` (`delete[]`)

Comment: @AndyG So `delete[] v` in this case?

Comment: @Andrew Was `v` allocated with `new[]`?

Comment: create a destructor then add `delete[] elem` to it

Comment: No. You need a destructor for your Vector class. However this issue has nothing at all to do with cin / cout.

Comment: Do you need to pause the console at the end of the program?  On some platforms, the console window terminates quickly after the program finishes so people don't think there was any output.

Comment: Are you running g++ under Linux? If running with MinGW/Cygwin under Windows [Avast antivirus might be a factor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console).

Comment: Don't you get a error message? I compile it in my Mac, it make a couple of error in  constructor. after I fix it, It works.

Comment: ***it make a couple of error in constructor. after I fix it, It works.*** You most likely did not have c++11 enabled. Or do not have a c++11 capable compiler.

Comment: I just edited the code to include a destructor in my class but it still doesn't run. It just hangs as soon as I execute `./vector_3`. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ***It just hangs as soon as I execute ./vector_3*** Did you type the 20 numbers each separated by a space and hit return?

Answer (score 0):

The program works perfectly fine. I personally think you are entering the wrong numbers. If you actucally wrote the code, you would know how it works but you say that you're new but I don't think someone that cant understand how someone cant read the code correctly be able to do vectors.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not entering in any numbers. I hardcoded in 20 when I call read_and_sum from main.

Comment: @Andrew `cin` is used to read from input, so obviously you must input something for the program to run at all

Comment: @Andrew: I think we found your problem then... You need to be giving your program input!

Comment: @Andrew: I should note that this was mentioned in the very first comment on your question!!!

Comment: @AndyG - ok I changed up read_and_sum function and main. Trying to wrap my head around cin! Thanks for pointing it out!