# IDE showing blank console

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ide, codeblocks, antivirus

It's been days since I try to make my IDE (Code::Blocks version 13.12, I tried on 10.05 too) work. Any program (including a simple Hello World! program) I would make would show a black console showing nothing but an " _ ". I have made an exception in my antivirus (Avast!) for the file containing the IDE) but the same thing happens . I have tried re-installing twice, i have tried resetting the compiler and debugger's settings to default, auto-detecting toolchain executables ,but the same thing happens.

I have tried rebooting my computer several times, same thing happens.
I would like to know what I can do to solve this problem , because I don't want to get another complicated compiler (I am a beginner,) , as Code::Blocks fits my needs perfectly.

The following codes produces a blank console:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Share your code once

Comment: #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}

Comment: Which OS u r running ?

Comment: I think you will have to add an exception for the directory holding your executable.

Comment: If you turn off avast does the program then run?

Comment: Is there anything i should do ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running my c++ code gives me a blank console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem, with Eclipse, Visual Studio and then with Code::Blocks (I tested them all). I suggest you follow this video tutorial after you confirm the problem persists with a second IDE : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOGU8fC3bvU&index=6&list=LLHcXdIeBMN4XYRZAk4IeXmg&spfreload=10 . It will take you step by step on how to install a given compiler.