# Anyone know why my Hello World in C++ isn't working out?

Tags: c++

Does anyone know why my Hello world won't print anything?

Here is the process I went through so far:

- I downloaded Visual Studio 2015.
- I created a new project and named it Hello world and checked empty to remove the pre compiled headers.
- After that I went to the source tab >insert new item and made a new item, the main function, and named it main.cpp.
- After writing my code I pressed ctrl+5 and the command prompt appears, but it's blank.

VS also tells me that my project is out of date before I build it, but I heard this isn't anything to worry about.

Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    return 0;

    cin.get();
}
```

And a picture of what I'm getting after pressing ctrl+5 and build. 
[image]

Comment: Why are you defragmenting your drive?

Comment: Placing statements after `return` won't be executed.

Comment: Check if your antivirus is blocking the execution.

Comment: Agreed. If you are using Avast disable it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console

Comment: @drescherjm Good find, I was trying to find that same question.

Comment: @Wavey the code in the picture doesn't match the code you posted in the question

Answer (score 5):

The `return 0` line is going to end the program before `cin.get()` gets executed.

Flip the order of `return 0` and `cin.get()`.