# Console window shows no output on running program on code:blocks13.12

Tags: c++, console, codeblocks

I am having this issue on running any c/c++ program in **Code:Blocks 13.12** on windows 10 the console window appears but no result is displayed.
FOr ex:-

[below is the program log and image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeVLx.png)

I have tried to reinstall code blocks from lot different links but result is same.

Comment: Disable avast and try again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console

Comment: Disabling Avast worked for me.
Thanks!