# fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory 3

Tags: c++, include, codeblocks, iostream

A number of answers to this exact error have been put upon this website but I am quite the beginner to C++ and Code::Block so i'm afraid I do not understand them.

I have been following a very simple C++ tutorial that started me out with one simple program that I was told to copy and paste into the compiler.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout<<"HEY, you, I'm alive! Oh, and Hello World!\n";
  cin.get();

  return 1;
}
```

I actually did not write any of this code so my own syntax errors cannot be an issue. Basically that means I'm out of ideas for troubleshooting. Any ideas as to why I can't run this?

Okay so saving the file as a .cpp worked for the building, but when my program actually runs nothing appears in the menu that pops up in which, I assume, the text is supposed to appear. Again, I'm decent at troubleshooting but this code has been confirmed to work by thousands of others and there must be something else wrong.

Comment: You must set the right path to _include files_ in CodeBlocks. Go to Settings->Compiler and then select the _Search directories_ tab.

Comment: Late last year it was "popular" for Avast anti-virus to [eat the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690697/running-my-c-code-gives-me-a-blank-console). Could that be it?

Comment: Omg you were totally right. Thanks alot! (I would have never guessed that)

Answer (score 1):

Save your file in `.cpp` format instead of `.c` format which is default for Code::Blocks. Your workspace(that is the file where you saved this code in) will be renamed to `xyz.cpp` and you can easily check this fact in the tab.Furthermore, change the `cout` and `cin` statements to `std::cout` and `std::cin`.

Just to make sure we are on the same page.Goto `Settings`>>>`Compiler`.Selected compiler should be `GNU GCC compiler`. Goto `Toolchain Executables` tab and autodetect the compiler's installation directory (should be something like `CodeBlocks\MinGW`).

Comment: I used the same code in CodeBlocks and it works no problems. Try building again and executing. The path for include statements is set automatically by CodeBlocks itself. Just try running the program after reopening CodeBlocks

Comment: Would there be a difference between opening the project as the project file versus the C++ Source File?

Comment: Nope, from what I understand its just easier to build a single C++ file instead of the entire project. So, the output should give you a result but the building of a project will take longer. That is the only difference

Comment: Project Name\bin\Debug\Project Name.exe                                                   is what is specifically on the program if that helps. I'm not entirely sure what the bin and Debug folders are for. And std:cout and cin did not change anything either

Comment: Okay yeah my compiler is the same

Comment: See you have created a project and its best to goto CodeBlocks wiki and find out the right way to go about that. But, to run your code simply goto `New`>>`Empty File`. Copy paste the code as given in the question above. Then remember to save your file in `.cpp` format. It SHOULD  work. If THIS  fails. Seek more help and trying reinstalling CodeBlocks as administrator. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your time but I've still got nothing. Yeah I guess I'll re install and try tinkering with the settings at some point. You know we don't have these sorts of problems when dealing with Arduino XD *that was a face, to my knowledge there is no versioon of of Arduino known as Arduino XD. lol

Comment: LOL! Casey I'm not quite sure why this is happening. Maybe go through a [tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/introduction/codeblocks/) on [CodeBlocks](http://www.cprogramming.com/code_blocks/). Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Code::Blocks compiles using some built-in .dlls and i have sometimes found it needed the dll in the folder with the compliled .exe

if not that, try the console application template

i use TDM-GCC it compiles fine.