# Why does my loop not work as I am expecting?

Tags: c++, loops, cout

I have been learning c++ for about a week now, and I thought I had everything under control, but apparently not. I was mid program, and decided to hit run just to see how things were looking. The program runs, but never ends. I was expecting it to at least print the first cout statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int floors, rooms, i = 0;
    cout << "floors: "; cin >> floors;
    while (floors > i) 
    {
        cout << "rooms: "; cin >> rooms;
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: You never check if your input is successful or not.

Comment: Are you running Avast Antivirus? And using Code::Blocks?

Comment: Did you try a simple `Hello World` first?

Comment: OP appears to have vanished but check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/33691587/560648

Comment: _program runs, but never ends_ what do you exactly mean here? are you seeing some output window? If yes, what is shown in that?

Comment: OP, hello? Are you there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not "flush your output". Depending upon various settings at various levels of abstraction, the `floors:` prompt then may not be displayed until there's also more output to go along with it.

Your program, then, is waiting for input before you are visibly prompted for it.

Add `<< flush` to your `cout` statement to ensure that the text is shown on the screen:

You should also verify that the input to `cin` was successful, otherwise `floors` has an indeterminate value and your loop very well may go on "for ever".

```
cout << "floors: " << flush;
if (!(cin >> floors))
  throw std::runtime_error("Value provided for 'floors' could not be read into an int!");
```

Comment: Shouldn't `cin` and `cout` be tied by default, omitting the need for an explicit flush, unless you have explicitly changed the tying in your code?