# Does anyone knows why when I try to run programs in VS 2019 my antivirus detects it as a heur virus and automatically closes it?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, antivirus

Does anyone know how to solve this? My antivirus (Norton), says that the project in the VS2019`s directory that I just created is an infected file and that is dangerous for my pc...
[image]

Comment: What's your program trying to do? Also, Norton is garbage :P

Comment: Windows Defender is very capable, and doesn't often get in the way, and can be configured to avoid scanning directories, such as your project directory, or avoid virus checking specific processes (such as devenv.exe and cl.exe).

Comment: My program is a simple "Hello world" program that I just wrote in C++

Comment: You can probably configure Norton to ignore that directory. Installing Linux to get around this would be excessive. The issue is in using Norton, not in using Windows.

Comment: It's likely a false positive. One solution is to add your project directory to the antivirus' list of exceptions.

Comment: I recommend contacting the folks at Norton.  If you do receive a worthy answer, consider posting it as a self-answered question.  There are a lot of Q's on SO relating to antivirus software intruding on software development.

Comment: This type of problem is not unique to Norton. See: [Running my C++ code gives me a blank console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33690697/445976)

Comment: My advice is to exclude your whole development folder from the virus scanner. With that said be careful if you are a person who downloads compiled third party libraries / dlls. I nearly always build these myself from source from trusted sites.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your VS2019 project, it could be that Norton is right or it could be a false positive! Impossible to answer without any information about your project.